# PHP：Can php implement the function of the timed task on the windows

Tags: php, windows

I've got one problem that

```
$filetime_f = md5(filemtime("path.txt"));sleep(5);
$filetime_n = md5(filemtime("path.txt"));
```

and when I change content in the path.txt in that 5 seconds,no matter what , it remains the same,please give me a right function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The results of `filemtime` are cached (see the [notes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php#refsect1-function.filemtime-notes)) during one php process. So you have to clear it manually with [clearstatcache](http://php.net/manual/de/function.clearstatcache.php).

```
$filetime_f = md5(filemtime("path.txt"));
sleep(5);
clearstatcache();
$filetime_n = md5(filemtime("path.txt"));
```